# Use of "in the sequel"

Tags: phrases

I have seen the following type of phrase in various academic articles and books.

> - Another important decomposition used in the sequel is the ...
> - In the sequel, we identify the position ...
> - the vector v (introduced in the sequel) must be considered...

At first, this use of "in the sequel" seemed strange, and I chalked it up to non-native English writing.  I would say something like "in the following" or "below" in a case like this.  However, I've seen it enough that I'm starting to question whether it's acceptable/standard English or not.

I can see an argument that by the etymology of the word, it can be used in this fashion.  The modern definition of sequel applies to books, films, and events.  What's the verdict?

Answer (score 6):

*Sequel* is from the Latin *sequi* ("to follow") and was presumably in use long before the modern concept of film and book *sequels* became so ingrained in popular culture. The use of *sequel* to denote 'that which follows' is valid and survives in academic literature, although it is likely to confuse lay readers.

Comment: If "sequel" confuses them, what they think of [sequela](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sequela)?

Comment: @JeffSahol: Good point, indeed _sequelae_ (the plural) was a word I first saw while working in medical data management. Can't find much at all on _prequela_, guess it hasn't caught on.

Comment: +1 @Snubian: The thing is that *prequel/prequela* would be a horrible malformation that could never exist in Latin, since the stem is *sequ-*, which means "follow", just as Greek *hep-* in *hepomai*. The *se-* part is not something that can be cut off, and the remaining *-qu-* would not be a morpheme, it doesn't mean anything. /rant

Comment: What about *sequal*?

Comment: I think OP's question is about the use of "in the sequel", used as a phrase.

Answer (score 2):

It is completely normal in academic writing, as you have discovered. It is a phrase, with a set meaning, which you have learned. What more is there to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

The word derives from Latin. Its dominant contemporary usage refers to a narrative or story of some kind. Technically it does also refer to "something that follows," or a continuation. I find it more distracting than helpful in the three examples you give.